# Extract the last component from a path string in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, path, powershell-2.0

I have a Question about shortening a string in PowerShell. So for example we have this code here:
`$path = "C:\Pow\temp\temp2"`

Now, I wanted to shorten this String, even if I do not know it, but what I know is that it is a Path. So from this Path I want to get only the name of the last folder so from 'temp2'. Does someone know with what PowerShell Code you can do that? I would be happy for an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell 3.0 and newer, use `Split-Path`:

```
PS ~> $path = "C:\Pow\temp\temp2"
PS ~> Split-Path $path -Leaf
temp2
```

In PowerShell 2.0, use `Path.GetFileName()`:

```
PS ~> [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path.TrimEnd('\'))
temp2
```